# "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

This seems like a simple error, but everywhere I look, I see people using Node.js in HTML somehow. I am using Electron and trying to make a simple replacement for the close button and everywhere I look at tutorials and questions about this, they tell you to use this code:

```js
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote

document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    window.close();
});
```

But obviously this doesn't work because `require` is a Node.js function. I can't move it into my Node.js code because it can't access the buttons and won't create the listener.

I haven't seen anybody else have this issue and I am *very* new to Node.js and Electron.

Is there a way I can run a Node file by itself from JS and take the outputs into the normal JS.

Comment: This is kinda tricky. I used to be fooled by this too, they're not actually using window properties in Node.js, they're using Node.js in the window properties. There is another process (file) that interacts between the renderer process and the main process. This means that when you execute Node.js code in your HTML, it sends it to the main process. I don't know how to do this specifically, but you can check out a tutorial: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/537/how-to-execute-a-function-of-the-main-process-inside-the-renderer-process-in-electron-framework

Comment: It says to use the `require` function in my renderer inside that, too. It still returns the same error. It's definitely getting closer to what I need it to do but still gets stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

So, this is a simple trick that lets you use require in your renderer process (window).

You just have to include the `preload` argument in `webPreferences` when creating the window:

1. In your **main process** (main.js), add `webPreferences` to your script:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
  }
});
```

2. Create a file called `preload.js` in the same directory as your main.js file, and add this to it:

```js
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("versions", {
  node: () => process.versions.node,
  chrome: () => process.versions.chrome,
  electron: () => process.versions.electron,
  // We can also expose variables, not just functions
});
```

And for the require function:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("require", require);
```

Now you should be able to use `require` in your HTML.

Learn more at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload

Comment: Do I have to use something different than `require` to access it or need to reference what require is? As I have said, I am very new to Node and Electron, so I don't really know what the code is doing that you provided. I know what the preload does, but not the code in preload. Also, it still produces the same error.

Comment: The preload.js code provides definitions to the renderer process. You can use these variables in your HTML/JS code.

Comment: For example, if you want the `require` function in your HTML, use `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("require", require)`. This will define `require` as the require function that you would use in the main process.

Comment: This made my program a white screen I can't exit out of without using task manager?